# Doxygen enum in namespace

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, doxygen

i'm writing documentation oh this code:

```
    namespace A {

    enum ENUM 
    {
        /// \var step to frame
        ENUM_1  = 0,            //!< val1
        ENUM_1  = 1,            //!< val2
        ENUM_2 = 2          //!< val3
    };

}
```

in result, comments values of ENUM don't displayed.

When i remove the namespace, everything is good, but no now

Answer (score 2):

You have to use this format:

```
    namespace A {
            /*!
            *  \addtogroup A
            *  @{
            */

            /// step to frame
            enum ENUM 
            {
                    ENUM_1  = 0,            //!< val1
                    ENUM_1  = 1,            //!< val2
                    ENUM_2 = 2          //!< val3
            };

            /*! @} */

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are placing the `enum` document header in the from place, it should be directly above the `enum` definition:

```
/// \brief Step to frame
enum ENUM
{
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but for the people like me struggling with global enums, functions, etc. under a namespace here is the simple solution without `\addtogroup`

Just be sure that you add a description for your namespace. With this, even autolinking works flawlessly.

```
/// this the namespace A
namespace A {
    /// step to frame
    enum ENUM 
    {
        ENUM_1 = 0,         //!< val1
        ENUM_1 = 1,         //!< val2
        ENUM_2 = 2          //!< val3
    };
}
```

For nested namespaces, you should put description for the namespace enclosing your other vars, enums, functions, etc.

```
namespace A {
  /// this the namespace A::B
  namespace B {
    /// step to frame 
    enum ENUM 
    {
        ENUM_1 = 0,         //!< val1
        ENUM_1 = 1,         //!< val2
        ENUM_2 = 2          //!< val3
    };
  }
}
```

By the way tested in **1.8.7**